# Error on first line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

When I try to execute my AJAX application I'm getting this error in the first line.

The error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

The line giving this error is:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: try JScript instead of Javascript in your declaration

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused between server-side languages and client-side languages I think. The directive:

```
<%@ Language="JScript" CODEPAGE=1252%>
```

is used to indicate the language you are using on the server; in ASP, this is [normally] just VBScript or JScript (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524311(v=vs.90).aspx), although any scripting language supported by IIS is possible if third-party scripting engines are installed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524720(v=vs.90).aspx for a full example.

For JavaScript on the client-side, you need:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

</script>
```

(Note that `<script language='JavaScript'>` is now deprecated.)

Comment: but that was a default line when i chose javascript page in asp

Comment: Then you either don't have a JavaScript engine on the server-side, or your error is coming from a different source. Where did you make this choice?